# Portable gdal2tiles.py

Tags: python, gdal, gdal2tiles, portable

I want to realize "Portable gdal2tiles.py" in both Windows and Mac environment.
"Portable" means, run script without installing something.

To realize this, I believe, we have to have such components:
1. Python runtime which is portable
2. libproj4 which is portable
3. libgdal/libosr which are portable

Are there such components? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The [Portable GIS project](https://portablegis.xyz/post/about/) solves this for you on windows machines.